# Opening a URL/File in app Crashes in iOS13 Xamarin

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios13

> **SOLUTION**
>   iOS 13 Redefined the override for openURL. I created an override from scratch, and things are working now.

Prior to iOS 13, my app handled a specific URI type, and it worked just fine. The openURL override in AppDelegate would get triggered as normal.

As soon as I try on iOS 13, after hitting 'open in my app' the app crashes immediately. I don't even hit a breakpoint inside "openURL". The whole stack trace is native code, so I'm not even sure where to begin with this one.

Is anyone else experiencing this?

EDIT: I noticed that when I click open in for my app, the app launches at the launch screen even though, I do have it running in the background already.

Still getting this issue. here is the stacktrace

```
    2019-10-15 01:40:58.937568-0400 PutSync[859:11094] Can't end BackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 1 (0x1), or it may have already been ended. Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug.
2019-10-15 01:41:05.783860-0400 PutSync[859:11094] *** Assertion failure in -[UIApplication _applicationOpenURLAction:payload:origin:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKitCore_Sim/UIKit-3899.22.15/UIApplication.m:7111

=================================================================
    Native Crash Reporting
=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

=================================================================
    Native stacktrace:
=================================================================
    0x102b0b9e5 - /Users/benbailey/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/729F23BC-8EFF-4406-87F3-71B3961D3F58/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7F7598E9-CD5D-4EA7-A532-39650024BCF3/PutSync.app/PutSync : mono_dump_native_crash_info
    0x102b00035 - /Users/benbailey/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/729F23BC-8EFF-4406-87F3-71B3961D3F58/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7F7598E9-CD5D-4EA7-A532-39650024BCF3/PutSync.app/PutSync : mono_handle_native_crash
    0x102b121f1 - /Users/benbailey/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/729F23BC-8EFF-4406-87F3-71B3961D3F58/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7F7598E9-CD5D-4EA7-A532-39650024BCF3/PutSync.app/PutSync : mono_sigsegv_signal_handler_debug
    0x7fff518c5b5d - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib : _sigtramp
    0x0 - Unknown
    0x102aff0ee - /Users/benbailey/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/729F23BC-8EFF-4406-87F3-71B3961D3F58/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7F7598E9-CD5D-4EA7-A532-39650024BCF3/PutSync.app/PutSync : mono_handle_exception_internal
    0x102afe1c9 - /Users/benbailey/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/729F23BC-8EFF-4406-87F3-71B3961D3F58/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7F7598E9-CD5D-4EA7-A532-39650024BCF3/PutSync.app/PutSync : mono_handle_exception
    0x102a822cf - /Users/benbailey/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/729F23BC-8EFF-4406-87F3-71B3961D3F58/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7F7598E9-CD5D-4EA7-A532-39650024BCF3/PutSync.app/PutSync : mono_amd64_throw_exception
    0x1051cb5b0 - Unknown
    0x102d34113 - /Users/benbailey/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/729F23BC-8EFF-4406-87F3-71B3961D3F58/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7F7598E9-CD5D-4EA7-A532-39650024BCF3/PutSync.app/PutSync : _ZL17exception_handlerP11NSException
    0x7fff23baa64d - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : __handleUncaughtException
    0x7fff50864d76 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib : _ZL15_objc_terminatev
    0x7fff4f6dfe97 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib : _ZSt11__terminatePFvvE
    0x7fff4f6dfe39 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib : _ZSt9terminatev
    0x7fff516ad795 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib : _dispatch_client_callout
    0x7fff516b0199 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib : _dispatch_block_invoke_direct
    0x7fff3652c49e - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices : __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__
    0x7fff3652c18c - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices : -[FBSSerialQueue _queue_performNextIfPossible]
    0x7fff3652c69b - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices : -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource]
    0x7fff23b0d271 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
    0x7fff23b0d19c - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : __CFRunLoopDoSource0
    0x7fff23b0c974 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : __CFRunLoopDoSources0
    0x7fff23b0767f - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : __CFRunLoopRun
    0x7fff23b06e66 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : CFRunLoopRunSpecific
    0x7fff38346bb0 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices : GSEventRunModal
    0x7fff47578dd0 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : UIApplicationMain
    0x109090cc2 - Unknown
    0x109090a13 - Unknown
    0x1084ee1e3 - Unknown
    0x102b15585 - /Users/benbailey/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/729F23BC-8EFF-4406-87F3-71B3961D3F58/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7F7598E9-CD5D-4EA7-A532-39650024BCF3/PutSync.app/PutSync : mono_jit_runtime_invoke
    0x102c34137 - /Users/benbailey/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/729F23BC-8EFF-4406-87F3-71B3961D3F58/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7F7598E9-CD5D-4EA7-A532-39650024BCF3/PutSync.app/PutSync : mono_runtime_invoke_checked
    0x102c396ec - /Users/benbailey/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/729F23BC-8EFF-4406-87F3-71B3961D3F58/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7F7598E9-CD5D-4EA7-A532-39650024BCF3/PutSync.app/PutSync : mono_runtime_exec_main_checked
    0x102a81e12 - /Users/benbailey/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/729F23BC-8EFF-4406-87F3-71B3961D3F58/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7F7598E9-CD5D-4EA7-A532-39650024BCF3/PutSync.app/PutSync : mono_jit_exec
    0x102d43cde - /Users/benbailey/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/729F23BC-8EFF-4406-87F3-71B3961D3F58/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7F7598E9-CD5D-4EA7-A532-39650024BCF3/PutSync.app/PutSync : xamarin_main
    0x102a59487 - /Users/benbailey/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/729F23BC-8EFF-4406-87F3-71B3961D3F58/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7F7598E9-CD5D-4EA7-A532-39650024BCF3/PutSync.app/PutSync : main
    0x7fff516ecd29 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib : start

=================================================================
    Basic Fault Address Reporting
=================================================================
Memory around native instruction pointer (0x102beaab4):0x102beaaa4  47 20 5d c3 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 55 48 89 e5  G ].........UH..
0x102beaab4  8b 47 20 a9 00 00 00 02 75 0c a9 00 00 00 10 75  .G .....u......u
0x102beaac4  26 48 8b 07 5d c3 48 8d 3d c0 ee 20 00 48 8d 35  &H..].H.=.. .H.5
0x102beaad4  3d ea 20 00 48 8d 0d b1 ea 20 00 ba 79 03 00 00  =. .H.... ..y...

=================================================================
    Managed Stacktrace:
=================================================================
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain <0x00251>
      at UIKit.UIApplication:Main <0x000b2>
      at UIKit.UIApplication:Main <0x00132>
      at PutSync.Application:Main <0x00092>
      at <Module>:runtime_invoke_void_object <0x00198>
=================================================================
```

Comment: You might wanna add the stacktrace anyway

Comment: facing the same issue :)

Comment: added issue https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/issues/390

Comment: Can you please mark your answer which will help more people with same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **SOLUTION** iOS 13 Redefined the override for openURL. I created an
>   override from scratch, and things are working now.

Answer (score 0):

A simple restart of your mac will fix the issue.

Comment: A restart of what? I haven't had any luck and this issue has persisted for a while.

Comment: restart ur mac :)

Comment: @Kikootwo Great ! Can you please provide your solution as the answer :)

Comment: Can you please show the code on how you implemented the override, I had used `LoadRequest` function with url and am curious on how you have done. You can accept you own answer :)